# Haskell - How to combine two monadic Maybe functions into a single function

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

Let's say I have these two data records, X and Y and following two functions:

```hs
f1 :: IO (Maybe [X])
f2 :: X -> IO (Maybe Y)
```

I need to call the `f1` first and then, for each element of returned list (stored in `IO (Maybe)`) call the `f2`, which would result in something like `IO (Maybe [IO (Maybe Y)])`. How can I compose them to get something meaningful, such as

```hs
result :: Maybe (IO [Y])
```

or

```hs
result :: IO (Maybe [Y])
```

?

Thanks a lot for any help :-)

Comment: It is not entirely clear what should happen in case it is a `Nothing`. Should this be treated as if it was an empty list?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem good point, in this use case I think we can safely treat `Nothing` as empty list.

Comment: `f1` is not a function; it's an `IO` action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A candidate could be:

```
result :: IO (Maybe [Y])
result = f1 >>= fmap sequenceA . mapM f2 . concat
```

Here `concat` is a function [**`concat :: Foldable f => f [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concat) that will convert a `Nothing` to an empty list, and a `Just xs` to `xs`.

We can then make a `mapM f2` to generate an `IO [Maybe a]`, and [**`fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap) with [**`sequenceA :: (Applicative f, Traversable t) => t (f a) -> f (t a)`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequenceA) to convert an `IO [Maybe Y]` to an `IO (Maybe [Y])`.

`sequenceA` will return a `Nothing` if the list contains one or more `Nothing`s, and return a `Just xs` if the list contains only `Just`s with `xs` the values that originally have been wrapped in `Just`s.

Comment: This one made that for me. Thanks for explaining the source code in detail, this is extra helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Essentially it's using `fmap sequenceA . sequenceA . fmap f2`.

Using `do` syntax and breaking it down one step at a time:

`result` and `result'` gives you the same result.

```
data X = X
data Y = Y

f1 :: IO (Maybe [X])
f1 = undefined

f2 :: X -> IO (Maybe Y)
f2 = undefined

result :: IO (Maybe [Y])
result = do
 f1' <- f1
 case f1' of
   Just f1'' -> do
     let a = fmap f2 f1'' :: [IO (Maybe Y)]
     let b = sequenceA a :: IO [Maybe Y]
     fmap sequenceA b :: IO (Maybe [Y])
   Nothing -> pure Nothing

result' :: IO (Maybe [Y])
result' = do
 f1' <- f1
 case f1' of
   Just f1'' -> do
     fmap sequenceA . sequenceA . fmap f2 $ f1''
   Nothing -> pure Nothing
```

Answer (score 3):

**note**: this answer is not very suitable for Haskell newcomers because it involves a monad transformer.

Once we start mixing `IO` with the processing and generation of lists, I tend to jump straight away to the [`Stream`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.2.0/docs/Streaming.html#t:Stream) monad transformer from [streaming](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming), that allows you to cleanly  interleave the execution of `IO` actions with the "yielding" of values to be consumed downstream. In a way, `Stream` is an "effectful list" that performs effects every time we "extract" a value from it.

Consider this version of `f1`:

```
import Streaming
import qualified Streaming.Prelude as S
import Data.Foldable (fold)

f1' :: Stream (Of X) IO ()
f1' = do
    mxs <- lift f1
    S.each (fold mxs)
```

[`lift`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#v:lift) promotes an `IO a` action to a `Stream (Of x) a` that doesn’t yield anything, but returns `a` as the "final value" of the Stream. (`Stream`s yield zero or more values when consumed, and return a final value of a different type once they are exhausted).

[`Streaming.Prelude.each`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.2.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:each) takes anything that can be converted to a list and returns a `Stream` that yields the element of the list. Basically, it promotes pure lists to effectful lists.

And [`Data.Foldable.fold`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:fold) is working here with the type `fold :: Maybe [a] -> [a]` to get rid of that `Maybe`.

Here's the corresponding version of `f2`:

```
f2' :: X -> Stream (Of Y) IO ()
f2' x = do
   ys <- lift (f2 x)
   S.each ys
```

Combining them is quite simple, thanks to [`Streaming.Prelude.for`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.2.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:for).

```
result' :: Stream (Of Y) IO ()
result' = S.for f1' f2'
```

With functions like [`Streaming.Prelude.take`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.2.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:take), we could read one `Y` from the result without having to perform the effects required by the next `Y`. (We do need to read all the `X`s in one go though, because the `f1` we are given already does that).

If we want to get all the `Y`s, we can do it with [`Streaming.Prelude.toList_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.2.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:toList_):

```
result :: IO [Y]
result = S.toList_ result'
```